# TFS OData - get work item types

Tags: tfs, odata

Is there a way to get all **Work Item types** for a project via tfsodata.visualstudio.com?

In documentation: https://tfsodata.visualstudio.com I was not able to find anything about it, and it is hard to imagine that something so important is not implemented.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such OData API to get the list of work item types. It's suggested to use [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/wit/work-item-types) if you use TFS 2015 or VSTS:

```
GET https://{instance}/defaultcollection/{project}/_apis/wit/workitemtypes?api-version={version}
```

Comment: That was my biggest fear. We used OData in past and it looks like it is time to rewrite whole thing to REST API...

I will accept your answer. Thank you for the confirmation and help..
Do you maybe know hot to set up oauth? Just drop me a link please, Or I will open another question, if you would prefer so. MSDN is full of holes heh..
e.q. https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/auth/oauth